# Explanation of a question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Please  I need an explanation to following problem:

Let $M$  a set and $K$ a field.
$x ∈ M $

$δ_x :M → K, y \mapsto δ_x(y):=1 $ if $ x = y, 0 $ if $ x≠y $

Prove that $ [\{  δ_x | x ∈ M \}] = Map(M,K)$  if  $|M| < $∞.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please provide some context so that we know how to help you. Where does this problem come from? Where did you stuck?

Comment: i found it in the internet. Actually it should be related to vector spaces but I can't understand the question

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_x$ is the **indicator function** of $x \in M$, i.e. $\delta_x(x) = 1$ and $\delta_x(y) = 0$ if $y\neq x$.

$\{\delta_x | x \in M\}$ is the set of all indicator functions of the items in $M$, so $[\{\delta_x | x \in M\}]$ is their **span**.

So we need to prove: given a finite set $M$, the linear maps from $M$ to some field $K$ is spanned by the set of indicator functions.

Proof: We only prove $\text{Map}(M,K) \subset [\{\delta_x | x \in M\}]$ and the other direction follows from definition.

Consider any $f \in \text{Map}(M,K)$. For $m_1, m_2,... m_n \in M$, we have

$$f(m_k) = v_k$$

for some $v_k\in K$. Now

$$f(x) = \sum_k v_k \delta_{m_k}(x)$$, therefore

$$f = \sum_k v_k \delta_{m_k} \in [\{\delta_x | x \in M\}]$$.

Comment: please could you explain this step $f(x)=∑_k v_k δ_(mk) (x)$
I think it is not equal to $Map(M,K)$ because it is the set of all functions from M in K which we actually do not know thus we cannot compare it with span. The span is all the possible combination, isn't it?

Comment: Actually I am confused because indexing the functions with the element of M makes the number of the functions $\delta_x $ limited to the cardinality of the set M, while we are trying to compare it with undefined number of possible function or mapping from M to K

Comment: @Thomas regarding your first comment: In writing the equation $f(x) = \sum_k v_k \delta_{m_k}(x)$, $f$ is an arbitrary **linear map** from $M$ to $K$, and the equation shows that it can be uniquely expressed as a **linear combination** of the indicator functions $\delta_{m_k}$. Here the $\text{Map}(M,K)$ should mean **linear** maps from $M$ to $K$, not all possible maps $K^M$. The span is all the possible **linear** combinations of the spanning set.

Comment: @Thomas regarding your second comment: Yes, the number indicator functions $\delta_x$ is limited to the cardinality of $M$. However, the span of all such functions will form a linear space with infinite cardinality, and with dimension $|M|$. Hope this helps!

Comment: The function is not arbitrary because it is defined in the question. Additionally, you did not make use of this defined function. One more thing, don't we have to prove that the Map(M, K) is a vector space then the functions $\delta $ are only a set of vector in Map(M, K)?

Comment: We pick an element $f$ from $\text{Map}(M,K)$ and we want to prove $f \in [\{\delta_x : x \in M\}]$ to complete the proof. $f$ is an arbitrary linear map from $M$ to $K$, or an arbitrary element from $\text{Map}(M,K)$. On the other thing - yes $\text{Map}(M,K)$ is a vector space, and the $\delta_x$ functions are a finite set of vectors, that form a basis of this vector space. Hence their span is the vector space, denoted by $[\{\delta_x : x \in M\}] = \text{Map}(M,K)$. Hope this clears up things.